# how to delete and create only specific folder in all sub folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete only one sub folder, that sub folder is presented in many folders.

For example, I have one parent folder `Main source`, and `Main Source` contains more than 100 sub folders.

Each folder has a few common folders like `child_AB`, `child_BC`.

I want to delete all child folders in "Parent" sub folder using batch file.

Can you please tell me how to do?

---

Adding example

Parent folder presented in D drive --> `D:\Main_Source`.

Main_Source contains following folders

```
LDAP_A1
LDAP_A2
LDAP_A3
LDAP_A4
LDAP_A5
......
......
So on...
```

Each LDAP folder have `child_AB` and `child_CD`.

I want to delete `child_AB` and `child_CD` in each sub folder.

How to delete `child_AB` and `child_CD` in each and every sub folder using batch file?

I am new to Batch file coding.

Comment: Reading your question twice, I still have no clue what exactly you want. It sounds like a trivial use of `for /d /r`, but I can't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootdir=D:\Main_Source"
FOR /D %%A IN ("%rootdir%\LDAP_*") DO (
  FOR /D %%B IN ("%%A\*") DO (
    IF "%%~nxB"=="child_AB" ECHO RMDIR /S /Q "%%B"
    IF "%%~nxB"=="child_CD" ECHO RMDIR /S /Q "%%B"
  )
)
```

The outer loop iterates over the parent subfolders in the root folder, the inner one iterates over a parent's child subfolders.

As you can see, this particular script just echoes a list of `RMDIR` commands instead of actually executing them. I would recommend you first to verify the paths it produces, and only then remove both `ECHO` keywords and run it again to proceed with actual deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script from Main_Source directory:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    if exist "%%a\child_AB" rd /s /q "%%a\child_AB" 
    if exist "%%a\child_CD" rd /s /q "%%a\child_CD"
)
```

You may add `echo` commands to debug it.